# Unable to submit data to MailChimp

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to connect my node.js with Mailchimp account. But after submitting the data it is not displayed in my MailChimp account.

```
const express=require("express");

const bodyParser =require("body-parser");

const request= require('request');

const https=require("https");



const app=express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){

  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});

app.post("/",function(req,res){

  const first=req.body.first;


  const second=req.body.second;

  const email=req.body.email;

  console.log(first,second);

  var data={

    members:[
      {
        email_address:email,

        status: "subscribed",

        merge_fields:{

          Fname:first,

          Lname :second
        }

      }
    ]

  };

const jsonData=JSON.stringify(data);

const url="https://us1.admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/e64eb8d60f";

const options={

  method:"POST",

  auth:"priyam:62d22c2957f10e380ffe9b8a5af27670-us1"

}

const request=  https.request(url,options,function(response){

  response.on("data",function(data){

    console.log(JSON.parse(data));

  })

})

request.write(jsonData);

request.end();
});


app.listen(3000,function(){

  console.log("started")

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You shouldn't post your username and key on stackoverflow... I'd remove those for generic terms.
2. The url you are sending the request to doesn't look like the correct api endpoint to send messages... is that the web console url?
3. I recommend using one of the provided SDKs to integrate with Mailchimp. By doing so, you'll avoid any issues with the wrong url, like above, and probably have a better idea after reading the documentation of what you're trying to achieve.

https://mailchimp.com/developer/tools/